# Geoserver coverage display

Tags: geoserver

I am publishing Satellite images through Geoserver as 16 bits images. The images are very dark. I want to make use of the RasterSymbolizer in the SLD to make it brighter but I cannot make it work, Geoserver seems to fail to generate the raster.

Here is one of the SLDs I tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld
http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd" version="1.0.0">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>RasterEnhanced</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>A raster style</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Name>rule1</Name>
          <Title>Enhanced Raster</Title>
          <RasterSymbolizer>
            <Opacity>1.0</Opacity>
            <ContrastEnhancement>
              <GammaValue>2.0</GammaValue>
            </ContrastEnhancement>
          </RasterSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Additional information:

- version is 2.11, running on a Linux Ubuntu
- image is a 1GB GeoTIFF file with 4 16bits bands (R,G,B,A)
- response from the getMap request

  Error rendering coverage on the fast path
  org.geotools.coverage.processing.CoverageProcessingException: org.geotools.coverage.processing.CoverageProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
  org.geotools.coverage.processing.CoverageProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
  java.lang.NullPointerException

Actual trace in the logs

```
2017-07-17 12:02:04,721 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: Error rendering coverage on the fast path
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:358)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:273)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:143)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.executeInternal(GetMap.java:623)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:279)
    at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:125)
    at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getMap(DefaultWebMapService.java:320)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor300.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.geoserver.kml.WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.invoke(WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:62)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:36)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:74)
    at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:55)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy59.getMap(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor263.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.execute(Dispatcher.java:857)
    at org.geoserver.ows.Dispatcher.handleRequestInternal(Dispatcher.java:268)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:147)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:50)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
    at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75)
    at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerBasicAuthenticationFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73)
    at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.geoserver.platform.ServiceException: org.geotools.coverage.processing.CoverageProcessingException: org.geotools.coverage.processing.CoverageProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.directRasterRender(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:1096)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:356)
    ... 112 more
Caused by: org.geotools.coverage.processing.CoverageProcessingException: org.geotools.coverage.processing.CoverageProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.BaseCoverageProcessingNode.getOutput(BaseCoverageProcessingNode.java:343)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.BaseCoverageProcessingNode.getOutput(BaseCoverageProcessingNode.java:46)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.StyleVisitorCoverageProcessingNodeAdapter.getOutput(StyleVisitorCoverageProcessingNodeAdapter.java:141)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageRenderer.symbolize(GridCoverageRenderer.java:482)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageRenderer.renderImage(GridCoverageRenderer.java:968)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageRenderer.renderImage(GridCoverageRenderer.java:784)
    at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.directRasterRender(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:970)
    ... 113 more
Caused by: org.geotools.coverage.processing.CoverageProcessingException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.BaseCoverageProcessingNode.getOutput(BaseCoverageProcessingNode.java:343)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.BaseCoverageProcessingNode.getOutput(BaseCoverageProcessingNode.java:46)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.StyleVisitorCoverageProcessingNodeAdapter.getOutput(StyleVisitorCoverageProcessingNodeAdapter.java:141)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.SubchainStyleVisitorCoverageProcessingAdapter.execute(SubchainStyleVisitorCoverageProcessingAdapter.java:116)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.RasterSymbolizerHelper.execute(RasterSymbolizerHelper.java:78)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.RasterSymbolizerHelper.execute(RasterSymbolizerHelper.java:58)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.StyleVisitorCoverageProcessingNodeAdapter$1.execute(StyleVisitorCoverageProcessingNodeAdapter.java:102)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.BaseCoverageProcessingNode.checkExecuted(BaseCoverageProcessingNode.java:238)
    at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.BaseCoverageProcessingNode.getOutput(BaseCoverageProcessingNode.java:341)
    ... 119 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: Please add your sld and the log file error with logging turned up to develop

Comment: I think you should focus your question on 1) and leave 2) for a separate question if it remains a problem.

Comment: OK, I edited the question, will post the other one in a separate thread. Any clue of what is going on?